# How to route MVC so that I can post a form with a model.action parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hopefully this is an easy one for somebody out there.

I am trying to post a form to my MVC controller that happens to have an "action" property on the model.

Unfortunately, the model.action is resolving to the controller action, not the posted model's action property.

```
public class PostModel
{
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult DoSomething(string id, PostModel model)
{
  // id == 98f4
  // model.username == "TEST"
  // model.password == "TEST"
  // model.action == "DoSomething" NOT "TEST" as I was expecting.
}
```

Here is what I post:

```
POST -> http://localhost:7832/Forms/DoSomething/98f4?username=TEST&password=TEST&action=TEST
```

Please keep in mind I have no control over the form data being posted, so I cannot change the model's action property.  I need to be able to address this problem on the MVC server side.

How do I overwrite the setting of the action property in my model to the acction of the controller?  I would only need this functionality for one particular controller in my project.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show your routing config?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out the problem.  Actually it was with my use of fiddler2 to hit the controller action.  When I had the action as part of the URL, MVC would replace with the controller action.

When I made the action part of the request.body, and added the "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to the header, then the controller model had the expected values.